# MIN() MAX() BigQuery - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

The result of querying

```
SELECT 
Type
, val
, MIN(val) over (partition by Type) as min_val
, MAX(val) over (partition by Type) as max_val
FROM tabA
```

Gives the unexpected output

```
Type val min_val max_val    
1 A -52.50 -50.00 -64.00
2 A -50.00 -50.00 -64.00
3 A -64.00 -50.00 -64.00
4 A -58.50 -50.00 -64.00
5 B -66.00 -35.33 -75.33
6 B -73.00 -35.33 -75.33
7 B -35.33 -35.33 -75.33
8 B -56.33 -35.33 -75.33
9 B -44.33 -35.33 -75.33
10 B -75.33 -35.33 -75.33
11 B -57.00 -35.33 -75.33
12 B -69.00 -35.33 -75.33
```

where min&max are reversed. Is there any possible explanation for this?

Comment: Bigquery works good for MAX and MIN, I think it is just you confusing because everything is a negative number so the max looks "lower" but remember that in negatives, the lower the greater the number it is.

Comment: Sorted, the issue was the 'val' column stored as a string rather than a FLOAT64 as it should be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is not stored in a numerical type. Big query can order strings too, which is what is doing here.